# How to synchronize sprite changes (SpriteRenderer) in Photon Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, photon

So, when I press space, my players sprite changes to another sprite. How can I make it so that others see this? I have tried dragging the SpriteRenderer component to Photon View observable list, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `PhotonTargets.AllBuffered` parameter in the RPC call as this will send the RPC to everyone else and executes it immediately on this client. Used Photon once and not a pro. Don't know much has changed since then but this will likely solve your problem.

```
void Start()
{
    if (photonView.isMine)
    {
        photonView.RPC("changeSprite", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, null);
    }
}

[RPC]
void changeSprite()
{
    //Out Change Sprite code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!